# Terraform GCP Notebook instance scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, terraform

I am trying to set up a Google notebook instance using Terraform. 
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/notebooks_instance 
I would like also to add an instance scheduler (to stop the instance outside the business hours: start instance at 8AM and stop it at 7PM) for the notebook instance.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_resource_policy 
Howerver, from the documentation there doesn't seem a quick way to attach a resource policy to a notebook instance.
Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: I think you want to schedule the VM(s) to stop outside business hours. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop. But you don't have a handle to the VM(s). The notebooks_instance resource allows you to configure a post_startup_script...